# Why do I get a python37.dll error when starting jupyter notebook via conda

Tags: python, dll, jupyter-notebook

I just installed Anaconda3.7, 64 bit for windows. I used Anaconda Navigator to launch jupyter notebook. The notebook opened, but when I try to launch a kernel/notebook I get the following error:

> The code execution cannot proceed because python37.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

I even tried launching jupyter from the command prompt and the anaconda prompt but it doesn't work. In those cases, jupyter tries to restart the kernel 5 times and just quits after no success.

I have the python37.dll file inside the Anaconda3 folder next to the python.exe and I tried adding python37 to PATH, but nothing helps.

**Any clue what might be the problem?**

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issues by doing 2 things:

1. I uninstalled Anaconda and deleted all hidden files and folders that had to do with conda, anaconda, jupyter and python that were created recently.
2. I disabled the antivirus and firewall while installing (it appears that they were blocking some dll and Anaconda files from being installed correctly).
3. I reinstalled Anaconda

I had the same problem with the firewall after installing anaconda. I tried creating a virtual environment with "conda env create -f "environment.yml" but it never completed the creation until I disabled the firewall and antivirus.

I hope this helps others with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Errors related to python37.dll can arise for a few different reasons. For instance, a faulty application, python37.dll has been deleted or misplaced, corrupted by malicious software present on your PC or a damaged Windows registry.

For anaconda its caused due to pip installing library into anaconda environment instead of using the conda package manager.

**So you can download a python37.dll file online and move it to you anaconda directory which should solve the issue.**

Check this anaconda issue might be related
`https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1394`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @ashish singh, Thank you for your support. I downloaded python37.dll from this website (https://www.dll-files.com/python.dll.html). It was a 32bit and version 3.7.2150.1013, which was the same version of the file I had in anaconda directory. But when I replace the downloaded file with the one I had in the same directory, conda stops working (my windows is 64bit). I can't even initiate the base environment or do "conda list". Is it because they were modified in different dates? do I need to change other files with them? (the downloaded file is 3.46mb compared to 3.57mb of the default file)

Comment: If you could extract the packages install into a text file, I would recommend taking the list of packages. reinstalling anaconda and then installing all the packages back in using the text file. Just a suggestion, I'll try digging into more details to find a better solution.

Comment: still not working.Thank you for trying to help @ashish singh. Any other ideas? I tried uninstalling jupyter via anaconda and reinstalling but no change.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I will look into details if I could find anything. Will let you posted. Sorry for the late reply.